# Lisp: Pass &rest parameters to a macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to build a function to access records in a database as such:

```
(select :title "milk" :rating 7)
```

However, it's just returning all of the records in the database. I believe this is because I'm passing `&rest` arguments to a macro and it's interpreting the parameter name "fields" literally. I've tried removing `&rest` from my macro, but then I get an error about not passing a list. I've tried calling (list fields) in various places to no avail (in the macro, in the function that calls the macro, in the function that the macro calls).

The following code works as expected:

```
(select-custom (where :title "milk" :rating 7))
```

And returns only the records which match the arguments.

source code:

```
(defun select (&rest fields)
  (select-custom (where fields)))

(defun select-custom (selector-function)
  (remove-if-not selector-function *db*))

(defmacro where (&rest fields)
  `#'(lambda (cd) (and ,@(make-comparison-list fields))))    

(defun make-comparison-list (fields)
  (loop while fields
        collecting (make-comparison-exp (pop fields) (pop fields))))

(defun make-comparison-exp (field value)
  `(equal (getf cd ,field) ,value))
```

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, they can't make use of run-time variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to create a function version of `where`. But as a simple kludge, you can use `eval`

```
(defun select (&rest fields)
    (select-custom (eval `(where ,@fields))))
```

Answer (score 7):

You could just make `select` a macro instead

```
(defmacro select (&rest fields)
  `(select-custom (where ,@fields)))
```

You can check that

```
(macroexpand-1 '(select :title "milk" :rating 7))
```

returns

```
(SELECT-CUSTOM (WHERE :TITLE "milk" :RATING 7))
```